# Java- extend interface with parametrized method where I don't need parameters

Tags: java, interface

I have a interface:

```
 public interface ITrafficParameter<T> {
  public T generateParameter(T minimumNumber, T maximalNumber);  
}
```

And I am having three class which uses this interface with method generateParameters.
In two class I am using generateParameter method. with this two parameters (T minimumNumber and T maximal Number)
But
In third Class method generateParameter doesn't need this two parameters, it's implementation is shown below

```
  @Override
  public Boolean generateParameter(Boolean minimumNumber, Boolean maximalNumber) {
     return Math.random() < 0.5;
  }
```

Problem is in using in main class:

```
ThirdClass thirdClass = new ThirdClass();
Boolean flag = thirdClass.generateParameter(Here not needed parameters to implementing)
```

But in other class (implemented this interface,parameters are used)

Like You see I don't need this two parameters here and my question- can I override this method to work without parameters? or mayby can I define method generateParameter in Interface something like generateParameter(T...) - I don't remember...
Please for help  I

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem?

Comment: You could use variable arguments as you mentioned: `public T generateParameter(T...items);`. But this can make things confusing, as you'd be accepting parameters as an array, meaning you'd have to check the length first to ensure theres items, then ensure its the right amount of items before continuing. You could just create another method so you don't show any false intentions (since you only need a min and max, using varags could confuse the client), but that'll remove the possibility of using your interface as a functional interface. What are you iltimately trying to do?

Comment: There is nothing forcing you to always use the second parameter. You may take in two parameters but use only one of them.

Comment: Your interface `ITrafficParameter` represents a _role_ that your implementations must comply with. The contract for your method is to take two arguments and return a result depending on those arguments. If you have a class whose implementation does not need the arguments, then it clearly has another role and should not implement this interface at all!

Comment: Thanx @Seelenvirtuose - I will consider this

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments. More over, your `ThirdClass` returns a `Boolean` instead of a `T` (which you might want to specify to `public interface ITrafficParameter<T extends Number>`). If you need another method signature, i.e. without minimum and maximum parameters and returning a `Boolean` anstead of a `T`, just declare a second method in your interface.